# Why Kotlin use operator modifier outside of operator overloading?

Tags: kotlin

I'm a bit confused on the usage of `operator` modifier in Kotlin. For example, Kotlin use `operator` modifier during destructuring declaration and properties delegation which, IMHO (pardon my ignorance), a bit confusing since both scenarios are outside of operator overloading.

Destructuring:

```
operator fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.iterator(): Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> = entrySet().iterator()
operator fun <K, V> Map.Entry<K, V>.component1() = getKey()
operator fun <K, V> Map.Entry<K, V>.component2() = getValue()

for ((key, value) in map) {
    // ...
}
```

Properties delegation:

```
interface ReadOnlyProperty<in R, out T> {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>): T
}

interface ReadWriteProperty<in R, T> {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>): T
    operator fun setValue(thisRef: R, property: KProperty<*>, value: T)
}
```

Comment: In all these cases, the method is not called via its name (`getValue()`, etc.); instead it's called via other syntax.  So presumably the intent is to make that clear by having the grammar enforce that these cases are prefixed with the `operator` keyword.

Comment: Probably there could be a better keyword, something like `convention fun`, but there already was `operator fun`, and I doubt anyone needs two keywords instead of one. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume in Kotlin `operator` means "accessed by a name convention", which is true for operators (`plus()`, `minusAssign()`, etc), component accessors (`component1()`, etc), for-loop accessors (`iterator`, `next`, `hasNext`) and delegate accessors (`getValue`, etc)